# attach capture from scanner as (PDF) to web browser

Tags: javascript, browser, plugins, attachment, twain

I developed a web app that can upload PDF attachments and my client want to add this attachments directly from papers scanner.

what is the best solution to do this?

Some questions on my mind :

1- is there any scanner app supporting that?

2- is there any browser plugin?

3- any "free or cheap" JS or PHP library?

I really don't know where to start so please any advice will help

Answer (score 0):

I was looking into the same thing and found out there are some really expensive web-based TWAIN SDKs. Most of the free web-based TWAINs are no longer valid since they only work in Internet Explorer which have been deprecated. A recently came across a relatively cheaper one called Codesharks so do check it out if you are interested.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).